# If $a^2 = b^2$ in a field, then $a = b$ or $a = -b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $a^2 = b^2$ **in a field**, then $a = b$ or $a = -b$

I know that a field is a commutative, division ring by definition.

Hence if $a^2 = b^2$ in a field, then we have $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ where we can say $a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a+b)$ because $$(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 +ab - ba - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$$ where $ab = ba$ by commutativity.

Hence we can say that $(a - b)(a + b) = 0$, which is only true if $a - b = 0$ or $a + b = 0$. If the first is true, then $a = b$ and if the second is true $a = -b$. Hence proved.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Also, note that you in fact only need to work in an integral domain (a ring where $xy = 0$ implies either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$).

Comment: @MarkSaving You also need commutativity...

Comment: @DanThousand I guess so. I have only done minimal work with noncommutative algebra, so in my mind "ring" means commutative (even though that's not the universal convention).

Comment: In a field we do not allow $0=1$, so if $xy=0$ then ($ x=0$ or $y=0$),  otherwise we would have $0=x^{-1}0y^{-1}=x^{-1}(xy)y^{-1}=(x^{-1}x)(yy^{-1})=(1)(1)=1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: The claim is true if $0=1$.

Comment: @tomasz. The Q is about fields. But I see your point: If 0=1 then every x=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Indeed, your argument goes through in (commutative) integral domains, as well as in fields. (Recall that a field is an integral domain because if $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$, we may multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$ to see $y=0$.)

[ NB: this answer is a compilation of the comments, to help remove this question from the unanswered queue. ]